# Executing JavaScript Outside of the Browser, Cross Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, native

I'm thinking of building a basic tool. In the process of building this basic tool, I was hoping to learn a new skill. I was hoping to write the tool using pure JavaScript. The tool basically needs to be a reusable library. The reusable library will primarily call out to third-party command-line tools. Occasionally, there may be some file system level operations I need to include in the library like copying or deleting files. I would also like to add a UI to this thing.

I feel my idea breaks down because I want to do native stuff across environments. I do **not** want to use Java. Ideally, I would like to write my code using JavaScript. I do not know about Node.js, however, from what I'm reading, it seems like I could use Node.js for my reusable library. However, I'm not sure what I could use to interact with this library from a UI perspective.

Am I on to a good idea using Node as my runtime in this case? If so, is there a way that I can create a cross platform UI that can interact with this library? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of possibilities come to mind.

- [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit):

> node-webkit is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js. You can write native apps in HTML and Javascript with node-webkit. It also lets you to call Node.js modules directly from DOM and enables a new way of writing native applications with all Web technologies.

- [appjs](https://github.com/appjs/appjs):

> AppJS is an SDK to develop desktop applications using Node.js melded with Chromium.

- [Chrome Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) (without the nodejs part):

> Packaged apps deliver an experience as capable as a native app, but as safe as a web page. Just like web apps, packaged apps are written in HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS. But packaged apps look and behave like native apps, and they have native-like capabilities that are much more powerful than those available to web apps.

- [node-chrome](https://github.com/hij1nx/node-chrome): (light weight integration with chrome - you control/write everything)

> This module demonstrates how well Node.js and Google Chrome (as two autonomous binaries) can cooperate wihtout much programatic interfacing. Node-chrome is the absolute least amount of glue needed to create a desktop experience with Node.js. The module will run on platforms that Chrome and Node.js run on.

- Build/Package your nodejs code yourself:  Have it launch the users default/preferred browser pointing back at the nodejs service.

IMO: node-webkit is pretty interesting in that packaging (in a basic app scenario) is as simple as cat'ing a zip of your apps resources onto an executable.  Distribute the right executable for the right environment and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AppJS](https://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki) it is an SDK to develop desktop applications using Node.js. It also has tools for exposing native C++ bindings to your JavaScript. For the fronted you can use whatever front end framework you like such as bootstrap.