# How to bind nodejs with my application?

Tags: node.js, v8, chromium-embedded

I have a project that uses [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (CEF). I use chromium_dll_wrapper_project  only in my project. I have binded certain javascript functions using it. I was trying to implement filesystem now.

Since nodejs is such good i/o framework build on [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8), the same engine behind CEF, Can i somehow bind nodejs with my application so that i can access nodejs async file system modules using my application instead of running node.exe.

What i want is that when i process any javascript and if it has code of nodejs, it would run ?
What is the approach that i should take to do this ?

Comment: i found that appjs uses nodejs and cef. how do it do it ?

Comment: There are a couple of options like this.  See: [Executing JavaScript Outside of the Browser, Cross Platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929572/executing-javascript-outside-of-the-browser-cross-platform/17929794#17929794).  Each takes a different approach.  The information on how they do it is available in the respective documentation.

Comment: @dc5 I tried to find the documentation but could not get it. Can you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: thanks for clarifying your question.  I'll see if I can clarify my answer.

CEF is a great for putting a browser into a form as a control.  Like other browsers, this control can connect to a server.  The server then determines the content shown in the browser.

With that in mind, it appears you're looking to do file access server-side.  Sounds like starting node.exe and pointing it at the files you'd like to use is the best solution.  I know you've already dismissed this solution as less effective as you now have two processes.

As an alternate solution, perhaps the app that contains the CEF control could do the file access and write the content into the CEF control.

Ultimately it sounds like you need a clearer separation between what the app does and what the server it connects to does -- even if that "server" is running on the same machine.

Comment: by referencing the module javascript you mean to add in my html file, fs.js which is the module of filesystem for nodejs ?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Are you looking to run the async module?  If so, just add the references to the content inside node_modules you downloaded from npm.

Comment: just curious, the async modules would require event handled i/o system which is implemented by nodejs. how would it get that ?

Comment: Are you after `async` (https://github.com/caolan/async)? Or are you specifically after a filesystem load? It's probably wisest to use CEF merely to talk to a server, and let the server load up the necessary content.

Comment: Cef is being used to put a browser and in that browser i run my javascript, HTML, CSS. my javascript has nodejs file read and write function calls. How to make them work ?

Comment: Thanks, but i am loading my "local" HTML,CSS,JS package and want to do file system access using that CEF browser window. I want to use nodejs for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CEFODE](https://github.com/zcbenz/cefode):

> The cefode project is a special build of CEF, which aims at providing
>   node API to CEF users, so you can easily add native abilities to their
>   existing CEF-based projects without writing native C++ bindings. There
>   is also no changes to CEF's API, so the node API just comes for free
>   after relinking to the CEF library produced by cefode.